# Using Count To Split A Checklist Into 2 Columns in X++ Fetch Method

Tags: count, fetch, x++

Here is what I have so far, this is returning two columns, but each counter is stopping and then duplicating the same value over and over...

```
        if(lLogisticsControlTable.APMJobTypeId)

        select count (RecID) from jobTypeCheck where jobTypeCheck.APMJobTypeId == lLogisticsControlTable.APMJobTypeId;
            {
                counter     =   jobTypeCheck.RecId;
            }

        while select jobTypeCheck where jobTypeCheck.APMJobTypeId == lLogisticsControlTable.APMJobTypeId
        {
            counter1    =   counter / 2;

            halfCount1  =   counter - counter1;

            if(halfcount <= counter1)
            {
                halfCount++;
                jobListCheck1 = jobTypeCheck.Name;
            }

            if (halfCount1 > halfCount)
            {
                halfCount1++;
                jobListCheck2 = jobTypeCheck.Name;
            }

            element.execute(2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is near impossible to solve without more information and better variable names! You should also try to post more of the code as you are referencing table buffers and variables without showing how they were instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Brown indicated, it's difficult to understand the problem with half of the code ;)

However, I would suggest that you call the *element.execute(2)* method on every **second** pass through the loop?  That way *jobListCheck1* would be on the left, and *jobListCheck2* would be on the right hand side.  Finally you would then need to check immediately outside of your loop if you had an odd number of jobTypeCheck elements, and call the *element.execute(2)* method one last time remembering to set the *jobListCheck2* variable as empty beforehand.

Regards